# Python - OPCDA read from remote server with OpenOPC

Tags: python, dcom, opc-da

I have huge problem with OPCDA and OpenOPC. I should (must) read a set of tags from a remote server, I have no access to the machine in any way. I only know the IP and the OPC server name.

Testing OpenOPC locally with this code all work fine. Otherwise, changing the hostname with the remote one nothing work with 0x800706BA error.

```
import OpenOPC
import time

try:
    opc = OpenOPC.client()

    opc.servers()

    #change localhost to remote
    opc.connect('Matrikon.OPC.Simulation.1', 'localhost')

    srvList = opc.list()

    print(srvList)

    tags = opc.read(opc.list('Simulation Items.Random.Int*'), group='myTest')

    for name, value, quality, tagTime in opc.read(opc.list('Simulation Items.Random.Int*'), group='myTest'):
    print(name, value, quality, tagTime)

    for tag in tags:
        print(tag)

    except Exception as e:
        print('OPC failed')
        print(str(e))
        pass
    finally:
        print('END')
```

Anyone have any ideas on this?

Not having access to the server (set with anonymous logon), I have done DCOM configurations as much as possible.

Does anyone know a procedure for a possible solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Can any other OPC client connect remotely to that server? Because, if it cannot (which is most likely the case because the error code means "The RPC server is unavailable. "), what you ask for might be impossible (e.g. DCOM might be disabled on the server).

Comment: Thanks! Yes, other tools (As advosol lib and MATLAB tool), with dedicated user can connect. The situation has changed, a dedicated user will soon be available for the OPC connection but, with OpenOPC, the problem remains. Now, despite the application being run with the dedicated user (another server with the same conditions as the previous one), the generic failure error is returned (now I don't remember the hex).

Comment: You need to post the details of the (new) error you are getting.

Comment: @ZbynekZ sorry but I totally miss your response ‍♂️ Now, using same user and psw as the server, I receive error 80004005. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, 0x80004005 is the dreaded E_FAIL, i.e., "Unspecified error". So it's difficult to judge the cause of it.

Comment: Sorry, no notification ‍♂️ Solved the general problem.  Given the impossibility of installing the gateway, I managed to convince them to create an ad hoc user for opc